# Generic method to convert one enum type to another

Tags: java, generics, java-8, enums

I have two enum as below

**First**

```
public enum firstEnum {
    ALL_PRODUCT,
    SPECIFIC_COLLECTION,
    SPECIFIC_PRODUCT
}
```

**second**

```
public enum secondEnum {
    PRODUCT,
    COLLECTION,
    PRODUCT
}
```

I am trying to create a generic method to convert one type to another as below

```
public record EnumCasting() {
    public <E1,E2> E2 CastOneEnumToAnother(E1 enumFirst, E2 enumSecond) {
         return // some logic to convert
    }
}
```

Not sure how can I achieve this, any help will be appreciated. `firstEnum.ALL_Product should return secondEnum.Product, firstEnum.SPECIFIC_COLLECTION should return secondEnum.COLLECTION`

Comment: And what should be the logic first value of e1 = first value of e2 and so on?

Comment: The return type is E2 so I need to return second value.

Comment: What i mean how should the convertion work? firstEnum.ALL_Product should return secondEnum.Product, firstEnum.SPECIFIC_COLLECTION should return secondEnum.COLLECTION ... And why you have both enums as parameter?

Comment: @Jens yes you are correct firstEnum.ALL_Product should return secondEnum.Product

Comment: @Kayaman well I have lots of different enum which need one conversion to another. If I create each method which is not good

Comment: And if I pass two different enum types to your method, what should be the result? If the first one was { SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT } and the other { MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY }, then I have hard time imagining Java code that would guess that I probably wanted SUN mapped to SUNDAY, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think TacheDeChoco is on the right track, but he misses the necessary generics declarations. Also, since generics are implemented through type erasure, you need to pass in the class of the second enum type.

Assuming the mapping strategy is as simple as *"taking the corresponding enum values being at the exact same position"*, the following could to the job:

```
public record EnumCaster() {
    public static <E1 extends Enum<E1>, E2 extends Enum<E2>> E2 CastOneEnumToAnother(E1 input, Class<E2> e2) {
        int pos = input.ordinal();
        return e2.getEnumConstants()[pos];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(firstEnum.ALL_PRODUCT);
        System.out.println(CastOneEnumToAnother(firstEnum.ALL_PRODUCT, secondEnum.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it.

```
interface MappableEnum<E> { 
    E counterpart();
}

enum E1 {
    A, B, C;
}

enum E2 implements MappableEnum<E1> {
    AA(E1.A), BB(E1.B), CC(E1.C);

    private final E1 counterpart;

    E2(E1 counterpart) { this.counterpart = counterpart; }

    E1 counterpart() { return counterpart; }
}
```

If you want to have multiple mappings from the same enum, you can use `EnumMap<E1, E2>` to capture the mapping.  Build the `EnumMap` in the constructor of E1 using the same technique.  This way, the mapping between enums is explicit.

Trying to do the mapping implicitly based on ordinals, as another answer suggested, is a world of hurt.  If someone asks about the wrong pair of enums, you will either get a garbage answer or an exception when one has more constants than the other.  And even if they use it correctly, if someone later inserts a new enum constant into one and doesn't insert it in the exactly right place in the other, your code is broken.

If you want to be doing this kind mapping, the two classes are coupled, and you have to capture that coupling somewhere, either in the type system (`implements`) or as explicitly initialized data (`EnumMap`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mapping strategy is as simple as *"taking the corresponding enum values being at the exact same position*", the following could to the job:

```
public record EnumCasting() {
    public <E1 extends Enum<E1>, E2 extends Enum<E2>> E2 CastOneEnumToAnother(
            E1 input, Class<? extends E2> e2Class) {
        int pos = input.ordinal();
        return e2Class.getEnumConstants()[pos];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need return the value of the same position of second Enum, you can try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SecondEnum selectedEnum = castOneEnumToAnother(FirstEnum.ALL_PRODUCT, SecondEnum.values()); // ok
        System.out.println("Selected enum: " + selectedEnum);

        selectedEnum = castOneEnumToAnother(FirstEnum.SPECIFIC_PRODUCT, SecondEnum.values()); //exception
        System.out.println("Selected enum: " + selectedEnum);
    }

    public static <E1 extends Enum<E1>, E2 extends Enum<E2>> E2 castOneEnumToAnother(E1 enumInput, E2[] enumValues) throws Exception {
        int pos = enumInput.ordinal();

        if (pos >= enumValues.length) {
            throw new Exception("Not found value in position " + pos + " for " + enumValues[0].getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        return enumValues[pos];
    }
}

enum FirstEnum {
    ALL_PRODUCT, SPECIFIC_COLLECTION, SPECIFIC_PRODUCT
}

enum SecondEnum {
    PRODUCT, COLLECTION //, PRODUCT
}
```